# Hijacking Links From Website Using Browser Plugins

Tags: browser, plugins

I am in charge of creating plugins for all major browsers which will hijack links from specified website visited. I wonder if this can be done by any plugin. I mean if plugins has that level of control over the website visited by the browser under my plugin supervision?

When I say hijack it means, I should be able to read the anchor tag's href attribute value and to modify it accordingly. I know how to do that in Javascript and I know Google Chrome extensions are written in HTML, CSS & Javascript so this  seems to be working. Will it work for IE, Firefox, Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After huge research I got to know this is possible in Chrome, Firefox and IE. I am still researching for Safari.

Comment: some links to your research might make your answer useful to others.